# Jersey Response.ok() not giving 200 OK

Tags: java, http, jersey

This is the piece of code that I am using.

The ok(Object items) method is internally calling Jersey's Response.ok() method when items is null.

```
    MembershipRequestModel membershipRequest = null;
    membershipRequest = communityService.addUserToCommunity(communityId, userId);
    if(membershipRequest != null) {
    // Add code 303 if returning membershiprequest
    return seeOther( membershipRequest, 
                   String.valueOf(membershipRequest.getId()), 
                   MembershipRequestRestHandlerImpl.class);
    } else {
    return ok(null);
}

public Response ok() {
    return Response.ok().build();
}

public Response ok(Object items) {
  if ( items == null )
    return ok();

  return Response.ok().entity(items).build();
}
```

But, I am getting the response as 204 No Content which should have actually been 200 OK. I have tried it using RESTClient firefox plugin and cURL command on CentOS.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: please, add a code snippet for your `ok()` method

Comment: Hey Alex, I have added code snippet.

Comment: have you debugged, is items object null? if yes, it going to return 204

Comment: Doesn't ok() method correspond to 200 OK. Then, it should not return 204 No Content

Comment: If there is no body, 204 will be returned. all 2XX are success. 204 means success with no content (no entity body). http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: @fmucar : The above comment is the correct answer. Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no body, `204` will be returned.

all `2XX` are success.

`204` means success with no content (no entity body).

[www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)